# ResponseEntity not producing any output to curl or postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, curl, response-entity

Having an odd issue where I am able to send requests to my local spring boot web api via CURL i.e
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"userName":"bob","textMessage":"newMessage","timeOut":500}' http://localhost:8080/chats`

`curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/chats/username/bob`

`curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/chats/id/b4f1a2c6-74e7-444f-abc9-a72fc61ec515`

Here is the POST method

```
 @PostMapping
    @Async
    public ResponseEntity<String> postMessage(@RequestBody Messages message ){
        if(message.getUserName() == null || message.getTextMessage() == null){
            System.out.println("No Username or TextMessage");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if(message.getTimeOut() !=null && message.getTimeOut() < 0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        message.setTextId(id);
        if(message.getTimeOut() == null) {
            message.setTimeOut(60);
            message.setTimeOutDate(60*1000+System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        else{
            message.setTimeOutDate(message.getTimeOut()*1000+System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        System.out.println("Attempting save");
        messagesRepository.save(message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("id: "+id, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

I am not getting any output of any kind.

Please advise.

Edit:
Image of curl command not returning anything for the post, but in backend we see it working
[image]

Edit 2:
Ive printed out the reponseentity and it has the correct content, so the error is the return not actually outputting

Comment: Maybe it is bacause of `@Async` annotation since it switches the executing thread?..

Comment: I believe you are correct @kerbermeister I took out the async annotation, which I believe now may be overkill anyway since spring is multithreaded by nature and my controller methods dont call for async since none of them are long running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have `@Async` annotation on your controller, which is releasing the container thread immediately and processing your task asynchronously in another thread.

`@Async` can be used for fire-and-forget scenarios, such as sending an email, kicking off a database job, some long-running background task. Caller immediately gets the response, while a background job continues processing.